# Scrapy 1.3.3 xpath can not parse upnp xml file

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1</deviceType>
        <friendlyName>Linux Internet Gateway Device</friendlyName>
        <manufacturer>Linux UPnP IGD Project</manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL>http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net</manufacturerURL>
        <modelName>IGD Version 1.00</modelName>
        <UDN>uuid:75802409-bccb-40e7-8e6c-fa095ecce13e</UDN>
        <DeviceType>Fiberhome_IGD_Device</DeviceType>
      <ProvisioningCode>NULL</ProvisioningCode> 
      <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion> 
      <HardwareVersion>1.0</HardwareVersion> 
      <ManufacturerOUI>000AC2</ManufacturerOUI> 
      <ProductClass>Fiberhome_UPnP_Device</ProductClass> 
      <SerialNumber>01234560890123456</SerialNumber>            
        <iconList>
            <icon>
                <mimetype>image/gif</mimetype>
                <width>118</width>
                <height>119</height>
                <depth>8</depth>
                <url>/ligd.gif</url>
            </icon>
        </iconList>
        <serviceList>
                        <service>
                                <serviceType>urn:schemas-dummy-com:service:Dummy:1</serviceType>
                                <serviceId>urn:dummy-com:serviceId:dummy1</serviceId>
                            <controlURL>/dummy</controlURL>
                                <eventSubURL>/dummy</eventSubURL>
                    <SCPDURL>/dummy.xml</SCPDURL>
                        </service>
                </serviceList>
        <deviceList>
            <device>
                <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANDevice:1</deviceType>
                <friendlyName>WANDevice</friendlyName>
                <manufacturer>Linux UPnP IGD Project</manufacturer>
                <manufacturerURL>http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net</manufacturerURL>
                <modelDescription>WAN Device on Linux IGD</modelDescription>
                <modelName>Linux IGD</modelName>
                <modelNumber>1.00</modelNumber>
                <modelURL>http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net</modelURL>
                <serialNumber>1.00</serialNumber>
                <UDN>uuid:75802409-bccb-40e7-8e6c-fa095ecce13e</UDN>
                <UPC>Linux IGD</UPC>
                <ProvisioningCode>NULL</ProvisioningCode> 
              <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion> 
              <DeviceType>Fiberhome_IGD_Device_1</DeviceType> 
              <HardwareVersion>1.0</HardwareVersion> 
              <ManufacturerOUI>000AC2</ManufacturerOUI> 
              <ProductClass>Fiberhome_UPnP_Device_1</ProductClass>              
                <serviceList>
                    <service>
                        <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANCommonInterfaceConfig:1</serviceType>
                        <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:WANCommonIFC1</serviceId>
                        <controlURL>/upnp/control/WANCommonIFC1</controlURL>
                        <eventSubURL>/upnp/control/WANCommonIFC1</eventSubURL>
                        <SCPDURL>/gateicfgSCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
                    </service>
                </serviceList>
                <deviceList>
                    <device>
                        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1</deviceType>
                        <friendlyName>WANConnectionDevice</friendlyName>
                        <manufacturer>Linux UPnP IGD Project</manufacturer>
                        <manufacturerURL>http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net</manufacturerURL>
                        <modelDescription>WanConnectionDevice on Linux IGD</modelDescription>
                        <modelName>Linux IGD</modelName>
                        <modelNumber>0.95</modelNumber>
                        <modelURL>http://linux-igd.sourceforge.net</modelURL>
                        <serialNumber>0.95</serialNumber>
                        <UDN>uuid:75802409-bccb-40e7-8e6c-fa095ecce13e</UDN>
                        <UPC>Linux IGD</UPC>
                        <ProvisioningCode>NULL</ProvisioningCode> 
                      <SoftwareVersion>1.0</SoftwareVersion> 
                      <DeviceType>Fiberhome_IGD_Device_2</DeviceType> 
                      <HardwareVersion>1.0</HardwareVersion> 
                      <ManufacturerOUI>000AC2</ManufacturerOUI> 
                      <ProductClass>Fiberhome_UPnP_Device_2</ProductClass>                      
                        <serviceList>
                            <service>
                                <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1</serviceType>
                                <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:WANIPConn1</serviceId>
                                <controlURL>/upnp/control/WANIPConn1</controlURL>
                                <eventSubURL>/upnp/control/WANIPConn1</eventSubURL>
                                <SCPDURL>/gateconnSCPD.xml</SCPDURL>
                            </service>
                        </serviceList>
                    </device>
                </deviceList>
            </device>
        </deviceList>
    </device>
</root>
```

This is a upnp xml file, i want to use scrapy to crawl it, but when i use `scrapy shell` get above xml content, `view(response)` command result is fine, all looks good, but when i execute
`response.xpath('//root')` or `response.xpath('//manufacturer')` or `response.xpath('//device')`
i got noting, i don't know why? it's a scrapy xpath bug?
someone can help me? thank you.
BTW, forgive me my ugly english...

Comment: I suggest that you [read this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces) about working with XML namespaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot. response.selector.remove_namespaces() is working. my problem is solved. Thanks again.